# what are good ways to find team-mates on research and writing papers?

Tags: collaboration, research-topic

im a AI researcher and mostly interested in a field that is less attended in our university. i have some ideas to work on but i blieve it can have better results by working with exprienced people. is there any network that you can find interested people that want to work in special type of fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attend conferences on that topic and network, read papers on the topic and contact the authors with questions, suggestions etc.